# Possible to embed a youtube video in an svg?

Tags: iframe, svg, youtube, embed

Sozi is an inkscape extension that allows Prezi-like panning/zooming of an svg file when viewed in an svg-enabled web browser.  A youtube video can be embedded in a Prezi, and I'd like to be able to embed a youtube video (or any kind of video) in an svg.  I know that html links can be made in svg documents (and inkscape supports this directly).  Is there a way to embed a video (via an iframe or video tag?) into an svg?

Answer (score 13):

```
<foreignObject width="560" height="349">
  <iframe xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    width="560" height="349"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR-MOVIE-ID"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
</foreignObject>
```

That should do the trick. Be careful, that the `xmlns` attribute stays on the iframe element. `foreignObject` is [explained here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement).

Comment: Just tried that with an SVG in Chrome 15.0: It works. But only if the iframe with the video is not rotated (`<g transform=...>`). Also if there are multiple `<foreignObject>` with video, then only the first one is displayed.

Comment: That might be, because foreignObjects are laid one over another at the origin, if their `x` and `y` attributes are not set.

Comment: Note to anyone stumbling upon this answer, `foreignObject` is only fully supported in Firefox https://caniuse.com/#search=foreignObject

Comment: Um, I think you misread that page. `foreignObject` is not supported in IE11 and lower only. The feature that caniuse displays is “SVG effects for HTML”.