# Embedded iframe within SVG element

Tags: jquery, iframe, svg, embed

The problem that I am having is that I am trying to embed an iframe within an svg element using jquery, and I am unable to get the iframe to be drawn. Here is an example from stack overflow that is very similar to what I want, except that would like to simply display an html snippet:

[Possible to embed a youtube video in an svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134184/possible-to-embed-a-youtube-video-in-an-svg)

my jquery code is like this,

```
    function showTextToolbar(selectedGroup){
        console.log("here");
        var x = +$($(selectedGroup).children().get(0)).attr("x");
        var y = +$($(selectedGroup).children().get(0)).attr("y") - 30;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
        var newFOSvg = svgEditor.canvas.addSvgElementFromJson({
                "element": "foreignobject",
                "id": "textTool",
                "attr":{
                    "x":x,
                    "y":y,
                    "width":"360",
                    "height":"30"   
                    }
                });
        var newIframeSvg = svgEditor.canvas.addSvgElementFromJson({
            "element": "iframe",
            "attr":{
                "width":"360",
                "height":"30",  
                "src":"http://www.google.com",
                "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                }
            });
        newFOSvg.appendChild(newIframeSvg);
        canv.getElem("svgcontent").appendChild(newFOSvg);
    }
```

Basically, this code uses several of my pre-built functions (addSvgElementFromJson), to add elements to an svg root that is already present on the canvas. I'm just using a dummy link to see if the frame will show up. At runtime when I call the function, no errors are present, and the svg section is updated correctly, but nothing is displayed.

Here is the svg updated with the iframe and a couple of other objects:

```
    <svg width="600" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <g id="0ea5f198be28b719853b18c7390003e7">
         <rect id="svg_1" width="350" height="50" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#22C" stroke-width="0.5" x="20" y="40"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <foreignobject height="30" width="360" y="10" x="20">
      <iframe xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="http://www.google.com" height="30" width="360"/>
    </foreignobject>
   </svg>
```

I seem to have gotten the iframe to embed properly, but nothing is displayed on my svg canvas. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: By moving the foreignobject element inside of the initial group, I can get it to be drawn, but is empty. The iframe is still not being displayed. Also, by creating a dummy page with an embedded iframe, I am able to see the iframe contents:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0 Frameset//EN">
     <html>
      <body>
       <iframe src="test.svg" width="600" height="600"></iframe>
      </body>
     </html>
```

And the test.svg contains:

```
    <svg width="600" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <g id="0ea5f198be28b719853b18c739002923" name="text_free">
       <rect y="40" x="20" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#22C" fill="#ffffff" height="50" width="350" name="border"/>
       <text y="60" x="40" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="left" font-family="serif" font-size="12" name="data" opacity="100" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"></text>
     </g>
    <g id="0ea5f198be28b719853b18c7390003e7" name="text_free">
     <rect y="90" x="20" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#22C" fill="#ffffff" height="50" width="350" name="border"/>
    <text y="110" x="40" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="left" font-family="serif" font-size="12" name="data" opacity="100" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"></text>
    </g>
   <foreignObject height="500" width="500" y="200" x="70">
    <iframe xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="http://www.google.com" height="500" width="500"/>
   </foreignObject>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: My solution was to abandon the iframe all together. It seems that the content was being blocked due to the fact that I was embedding an svg element within a document, and then embedding another html element inside of the svg. For my particular case, the iframe was not the best solution to my problem.

Comment: I ended up just floating a div around my page with the toolbar that I wanted. Didn't need to draw anything on the svg for the toolbar. Works much better with the floating div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just floating a div around my page with the toolbar that I wanted. Didn't need to draw anything on the svg for the toolbar. Works much better with the floating div.

Update - For those looking to achieve my original goal, one must use jQuery to append an SVG namespaced Foreign Object node to base SVG.

Comment: That was not the question. If it is impossible to embed HTML into SVG dynamically with Javascript, explain why. And if you don't know, don't post an answer with an obvious workaround, as answer.

Comment: Seeing that I wrote the question, I never said that it was impossible to embed HTML into SVG, I simply stated that in my case it wasn't the best solution. Did you even read the entire post?

Comment: I gave an example of how I was able to embed an iframe in a foreign object tag. Maybe before you mindlessly down vote and berate me about an answer you should read the entire post.

Comment: I have read the question and answer and I have noted that you where the person who have written both. However even though your answer has satisfied yourself, it doesn't help others like myself that are looking for a way to add a foreign object into an svg using javascript, what the question was about.

Comment: I was able to embed an iframe using jquery. All you have to do is create a DOM element for the foreign object tag, (using an SVG namespace), and insert via any method you see fit into the current document. If you would like more help, (including code examples) I suggest you open a new question. I'm sorry I criticized you in my comment, but I did post code that inserts the foreign object into the svg element, answering your question.

Comment: I were only able to write a static SVG document embedding HTML using foreignObject, but when adding the foreignObject using Javascript it won't be rendered. However, I have used jQuery's append() method (with an SVG string as parameter) instead of addSvgElementFromJson() from svg-edit. But I were pretty sure that was the same problem your question was about. I would undo my down-vote, but it's not posible, unless you edit your answer.

Comment: I'm confused as addSvgElementFromJson() does the exact same thing, only using a JSON string representation.

Comment: I accomplished this a while ago - forgot how and this evening started to look around again to figure out how I did it. The one thing that is very memorable to me is that there was a problem modifying the DOM because manipulating the HTML DOM to inject XML wouldn't work because HTML isn't case sensitive and it would just result in DOM errors until - I think I had to define the document as XHTML and possibly jump through a couple other hoops. End result worked great tho.. Now if I can just find it..

Answer (score 1):

From within D3.js, I was able to use javascript to append an iframe to a foreignobject using a xhtml container

```
var the_container=the_foreignObject.append("xhtml:body")

var the_iframe.append("iframe")
    .attr("src", function(d) {
        the_url="http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1256572";
        return the_url;
    })
    .attr("width", background_width)
    .attr("height", background_height/2)
    .attr("frameborder","0")
;
```